# What does GetByCriteria return when no results are found?

Tags: nhibernate, return-value

I'm using NHibernate to retrieve a list from the database based on some criteria.

```
List<MyType> myList = GetByCriteria(...)
```

Does anyone know whether myList will be null or an empty list of MyType if no results are found that match the criteria?

I've been looking through the [NHibernate documentation](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/1.2/reference/en/html/) and searching in google but I can't find anything that tells me one way or another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest answer would be to test it... but I'd be astonished if it returned null. I'd *definitely* expect it to return an empty list.

Comment: yeah, you're right..I should have tested it... I've tested it now and it definitely returns an empty list which is what I was expecting. Some other developer had been writing code to double check that the returned list was not null and it got me curious at a time when I didn't have a chance to do a write test...so I did a quick search which pulled up no clues so I figured I'd document the question on StackOverflow :)